# Generate a .PO file from a .properties file using msgcat & concatenate the .po files generated into a single .PO

Tags: windows, localization, gettext

1. I need to generate a .PO file from a .properties file using msgcat from gettext package available for windows.
2. After it, using msgcat, concatenate the .po files generated into a single .PO (this would be the translatrion memory but in PO format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concatenating

Download gettext-0.14.4.exe from http://svn.softwarepublico.gov.br/trac/invesalius/browser/invesalius2/branches/slice_editor/req/gettext-0.14.4.exe?rev=2038

After installing it go to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" in command prompt. then use the command **msgcat "" "" --output-file=""**. After it I could concatenate the two po files successfully.